# Azure SQL Server Login/User Roles to Up and Downscale DB

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

Client has an Azure SQL Server with a SQL Database that is currently Standard Edition S1.

This is fine considering the database is mostly in idle mode, and data is sync'd to it once a day and extracted from it once a day.

However considering the solution is now in Production and the large amount of data is having a massive impact on performance. What took 3-6 minutes is now taking 3+ hrs.

Temporarily upscaling the database from S1 -> S6, performing syncs, rebuilding indexes, downscale database back to S1 seems like nice cheap way of turning a Bruce Banner database into the Hulk.

**My question is, what roles/rights assignment is required for a SQL Authenticated Login/User to allow them to perform UP and DOWN scaling in T-SQL?**

Also is this the best way to get Max Performance for least amount of cost?

Answer (score 1):

To perform the manual scaling, you can assign **Contributor** role to the database user. **A contributor can manage Azure resources but can't grant access to others.**
Please follow below image to assign contributor role to user on SQL Server:

[image]

As far as the scope of Standard S1 service tier SQL database, running T-SQL script on PowerShell or Azure Cloud Shell is the only best possible way to scale up and down your database. Please follow [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/scripts/monitor-and-scale-database-powershell) for more details.

But this is not the recommended way. As soon as the scope of database will increase and usage become unpredictable, it might be difficult for you to do this manual scaling. If you use General purpose service tier, it allows you to use serverless computing which gives the option of autoscaling.

**Serverless is a compute tier for single databases in Azure SQL Database that automatically scales compute based on workload demand and bills for the amount of compute used per second. The serverless compute tier also automatically pauses databases during inactive periods when only storage is billed and automatically resumes databases when activity returns.**

[image]

Please follow the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/serverless-tier-overview) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

**db_owner** is required for a SQL Authenticated Login/User to allow them to perform UP and DOWN scaling in T-SQL.

**Serverless** is the best way to get Max Performance for least(Pay per cost=exact) amount of cost.

**Contributor** (Grants full access to manage all resources, but does not allow you to assign roles in Azure RBAC, manage assignments in Azure Blueprints, or share image galleries.) **role** at SQL server level is better for User to allow them to perform UP and DOWN scaling databases via azure portal.

data related database_principals, db_backupoperator, db_ddladmin, db_securityadmin, db_accessadmin  wont work. **db_owner** is the only acceptable role/access that can be able to perform UP and DOWN scaling databases via t-sql in SSMS. I have tried like below:

```
--needs to be created in Master DB
CREATE LOGIN arulmouzhi_owner WITH PASSWORD ='User@12345g' ; --dummy password
CREATE LOGIN arulmouzhi_accessadmin WITH PASSWORD ='User@12345g' ; --dummy password
CREATE LOGIN arulmouzhi_securityadmin WITH PASSWORD ='User@12345g' ; --dummy password
CREATE LOGIN arulmouzhi_ddladmin WITH PASSWORD ='User@12345g' ; --dummy password
CREATE LOGIN arulmouzhi_backupoperator WITH PASSWORD ='User@12345g' ; --dummy password

--needs to be created in particular DB
CREATE USER arulmouzhi_owner FROM LOGIN arulmouzhi_owner;
CREATE USER arulmouzhi_accessadmin FROM LOGIN arulmouzhi_accessadmin;
CREATE USER arulmouzhi_securityadmin FROM LOGIN arulmouzhi_securityadmin;
CREATE USER arulmouzhi_ddladmin FROM LOGIN arulmouzhi_ddladmin;
CREATE USER arulmouzhi_backupoperator FROM LOGIN arulmouzhi_backupoperator;

EXEC SP_ADDROLEMEMBER 'db_owner','arulmouzhi_owner' ;
EXEC SP_ADDROLEMEMBER 'db_accessadmin','arulmouzhi_accessadmin' ;
EXEC SP_ADDROLEMEMBER 'db_securityadmin','arulmouzhi_securityadmin' ;
EXEC SP_ADDROLEMEMBER 'db_ddladmin','arulmouzhi_ddladmin' ;
EXEC SP_ADDROLEMEMBER 'db_backupoperator','arulmouzhi_backupoperator' ;

--ALTER DATABASE [testmaydevdb] MODIFY (EDITION ='Standard');
ALTER DATABASE [testmaydevdb] MODIFY (EDITION ='Basic');
```

if we try with ***other than db_owner***, we may saw like below:
[image]

Try under ***v-core based purchase model***, **General purpose** as Service tier and **Serverless** as Compute tier. As mentioned, advantages are Compute resources are **auto-scaled**​. Billed per **second** based on vCores used​. We can also **Configure min/max v-cores**. Based on database usage metrics/history, we can also set **Auto-pause delay**.
The database automatically pauses if it is inactive for the time period specified here, and automatically resumes when database activity recurs. Alternatively, auto-pausing can be disabled.

[image]